Is I Cor. 13 an insertion by a later editor?
Note: this question has something in common with and earlier query but the question here is not whether the chapter is a hymn. It is whether it was inserted into the text, perhaps by someone other than Paul

1 Cor. 13

11 When I was a child, I used to talk as a child, think as a child,
reason as a child; when I became a man, I put aside childish things.
12 At present we see indistinctly, as in a mirror, but then face to
face. At present I know partially; then I shall know fully, as I am
fully known. 13 So faith, hope, love remain, these three; but the
greatest of these is love.

Scholars have questioned whether 1 Corinthians may be a later insertion. The textual basis for this idea is that the chapter seems to interrupt the flow of the letter. The theological basis for it is that Paul generally affirms faith in Christ as the key virtue, but in this passage he makes human love more important.
Textual argument

[ch. 12] 30 Do all speak in tongues? Do all interpret? 31 Strive
eagerly for the greatest spiritual gifts.... [ch 14] above all that
you may prophesy. 2 For one who speaks in a tongue does not speak to
human beings but to God, for no one listens; he utters mysteries in
spirit.

The argument here is that Paul is not speaking about hope, faith and love, but about spiritual gifts generally, and specifically about the gifts of tongues and prophecy. An editor (perhaps Paul himself?) has inserted the wonderful chapter on love and slightly edited our chapter 14 to smooth over the interruption.
Theological argument

Romans 4:16  "For this reason, it depends on faith, so that it may be a gift."

Ephesians 2:8  "For by grace you have been saved through faith, and this is not from you; it is the gift of God."


Throughout his letters Paul emphasizes the key role of faith. We are saved by grace through faith, which is not a quality we exercise on our own but is a gift from God.   But here he says that love, not faith, is the greatest gift, and if we do not love, our faith avails us not. ("If I have all faith so as to move mountains but do not have love, I am nothing.") This argument tends toward the conclusion that the chapter in question was inserted by another writer - or if Paul inserted it, he did so without realizing that it calls into question the importance of faith as the key to our relationship with God.
The question: Should we take these arguments seriously? Is it possible that Paul inserted this chapter into his own letter?

And if someone else inserted it, should we still accept it as scripture - I really enjoy textual criticism questions and look forward to seeing answers (maybe I'll offer one), however I think this specific part of your question may be better suited on Christianity SE as it deals with Christian belief

@AviAvraham you may be right. I'll take that part out and consider asking it on Christianity SE

There is a third possibility, that the passage was written by Paul elsewhere and transferred to this location by the hypothetical editor of "The collected letters of Paul". This theory would explain a lot of odditiess in the other epistles.

If 1 Cor 13 is a non-Pauline insertion, it was done by someone who could imitate Paul extremely well because it uses Pauline vocabulary and Pauline themes.  Specifically:

Paul regularly emphasized "Faith Hope and love" as per 1 Cor 13:13
Col 1:5 – the Colossians were commended for their faith, hope and love which enabled them to bear fruit of souls won to Jesus.
1 Thess 1:3 – the Thessalonians were also commended for their:


work of faith




(exhausting) labor of love




endurance of hope in the Lord Jesus Christ.  This is the great formula of the persevering of the saints.


1 Thess 5:8 – one of the Christian warfare passages that helps the Christian to endure and persevere.by wearing, "the breastplate of faith and love, and the helmet of our hope of salvation."

Note the order of the virtues (1 Cor 13:13) – trust comes first, and means we trust in God for all things.  We hope for Jesus’ return and love others as He loved us.  Thus, these three great virtues are outwardly focused.  Paul discusses this, yet again when sharing that Love is the great motivation for keeping the law in Rom 13:8-10.
This final passage in Rom 13:8-10 is a theme taken directly from the Torah and the teachings of Jesus - see appendix below.
It is little wonder that Paul said that love was "the most excellent way" (1 Cor 12:31b) and advised that we "earnestly pursue love" (1 Cor 14:1).
In other passages, Paul emphasizes God's love for us as the prime motivator for our changed lives and spiritual motivation such as:

Rom 5:5, 8 - ... God has poured out His love into our hearts through the Holy Spirit, whom He has given us. ... But God proves His love for us in this: While we were still sinners, Christ died for us.
Rom 8:35, 39 - nothing can separate us from the love of Christ and God
Rom 14:15 - If your brother is distressed by what you eat, you are no longer acting in love. Do not by your eating destroy your brother, for whom Christ died.
2 Cor 5:14 - For the love of Christ controls us ...
2 Cor 6:4-6 - Rather, as servants of God we commend ourselves in every way: in great endurance; ... and kindness; in the Holy Spirit and in sincere love;
2 Cor 8:7, 8 - But just as you excel in everything—in faith, in speech, in knowledge, in complete earnestness, and in the love we inspired in you —see that you also excel in this grace of giving. 8I am not making a demand, but I am testing the sincerity of your love in comparison to the earnestness of others.
2 Cor 8:24 - In full view of the churches, then, show these men the proof of your love and the reason for our boasting about you.
etc, etc (there are dozens more).

Indeed, Paul uses the word "love" almost as often as he uses the word "grace" and "faith".
APPENDIX - Centrality of Love in the OT.

Lev 19:18 - Do not seek revenge or bear a grudge against any of your people, but love your neighbor as yourself. I am the LORD.
Deut 5:10 - but showing love to a thousand generations of those who love me and keep my commandments.
Deut 6:4, 5 - Hear, O Israel: The LORD our God, the LORD is One. And you shall love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your strength.
Deut 11:1 - You shall therefore love the LORD your God and always keep His charge, His statutes, His ordinances, and His commandments.
Deut 11:13 - So if you carefully obey the commandments I am giving you today, to love the LORD your God and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul,
Deut 11:22 - For if you carefully keep all these commandments I am giving you to follow—to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, and to hold fast to Him
Deut 13:3 - you shall not listen to the words of that prophet or that dreamer of dreams. For the LORD your God is testing you, to know whether you love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul
Deut 19:9 - because you carefully follow all these laws I command you today— to love the LORD your God and to walk always in obedience to him—then you are to set aside three more cities.
Deut 30:6 - And the LORD your God will circumcise your heart and the heart of your offspring, so that you will love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all your soul, that you may live.
Deut 30:16 - For I am commanding you today to love the LORD your God, to walk in His ways, and to keep His commandments, statutes, and ordinances, so that you may live and increase, and the LORD your God may bless you in the land that you are entering to possess.
Deut 30:20 - and that you may love the LORD your God, obey Him, and hold fast to Him. For He is your life, and He will prolong your life in the land that the LORD swore to give to your fathers, to Abraham, Isaac, and Jacob.”
Josh 22:5 - But be very careful to observe the commandment and the law that Moses the servant of the LORD gave you: to love the LORD your God, to walk in all His ways, to keep His commandments, to hold fast to Him, and to serve Him with all your heart and with all your soul.”
Josh 23:11 - So be very careful to love the LORD your God.
Matt 22:36-40 - “Teacher, which commandment is the greatest in the Law?” Jesus declared, “ ‘Love the Lord your God with all your heart and with all your soul and with all your mind.’ This is the first and greatest commandment. And the second is like it: ‘Love your neighbor as yourself.’ All the Law and the Prophets hang on these two commandments.”


thanks for your work on this. But even though Paul certainly mentions hope and love elsewhere, does he ever make love superior to faith?

@DanFefferman - In Gal 5:22 - Love is the first of the fruit of the Spirit.


For in Jesus Christ neither circumcision availeth any thing, nor uncircumcision; but faith which worketh by love. - Galatians 5:6

Paul is pretty uniform throughout his writings and 1 Corinthians is no exception.  Chapters 12, 13, and 14 address spiritual gifts in both a teaching and corrective fashion.
In short, the faithful recognition and manifestation of any spiritual gift will be motivated by love; if it is not thus motivated it is merely a smoke and light show garnering its own reward.  This love is described in chapter 13.

For now we see through a glass, darkly; but then face to face: now I know in part; but then shall I know even as also I am known. And now abideth faith, hope, charity, these three; but the greatest of these is charity. - 1 Cor. 13:12-13

The time frame emphasized by Paul here is "now", more accurately "just now" or "this immediate moment" as compared to "then" (when we see the Lord face to face).  At that time we will no longer walk by faith but by sight.
Paul is speaking of "now" (faith, hope, and love) abiding as compared to "then" the [consummation (end) of our faith; the salvation of our souls]. 1.  "Then" faith will have accomplished its purpose, "then" hope will have been actualized (who hopes for what is seen?), and "then" love, in all its unstained glory, will remain.  And not only remain, as do faith and hope in consummated form, but thrive and pulse within the life of the family of God forever.
Love will be greater "then" because there is no consummated end of its purpose.

The argument that 1 Corinthians 13 is an insertion by a later editor requires careful textual, theological, and linguistic analysis. Let us examine the key points systematically, particularly addressing the arguments presented and using the linguistic evidence regarding the verb εἰδῶμεν.
Linguistic Argument
The linguistic style and vocabulary of 1 Corinthians 13 align closely with Paul's known writings. The use of εἰδῶμεν (perfect subjunctive of "to know") in 1 Corinthians 13:2 is consistent with Paul's usage elsewhere in the letter, such as in 1 Corinthians 2:12 and 14:11.

In 1 Corinthians 2:12, Paul emphasizes spiritual knowledge as a gift from God: "We received not the spirit of the world but the Spirit from God, so that we may know (ἵνα εἰδῶμεν) the things freely given by God."
In 1 Corinthians 13:2, Paul again employs εἰδῶ to discuss knowledge in the context of prophecy and mysteries, further connecting it to love.
In 1 Corinthians 14:11, the verb appears in a discussion of understanding tongues, maintaining continuity with the themes of chapters 12–14.

The repeated use of εἰδῶ in various forms across these chapters demonstrates a consistent linguistic pattern. This supports the argument that chapter 13 is part of Paul's original composition, as it reflects his characteristic style.
Theological Argument
Faith and Love in Paul's Theology
It is essential to consider Paul's theological framework. While faith is undoubtedly central to Paul's soteriology (e.g., Romans 4:16; Ephesians 2:8), the primacy of love in 1 Corinthians 13:13 does not contradict this. Instead, it expands Paul's vision of Christian life and ethics:

Faith as the Basis; Love as the Fulfillment: In Galatians 5:6, Paul explicitly states, "For in Christ Jesus, neither circumcision nor uncircumcision counts for anything, but only faith working through love." Here, faith and love are not in opposition but in a complementary relationship. Love is the manifestation of faith in action.

Love and the Gifts of the Spirit: Chapters 12–14 address spiritual gifts, but 13 serves as a theological center, reminding the Corinthians that gifts are meaningless without love. This is not a digression but a deliberate rhetorical strategy to reorient the discussion around the ultimate goal of these gifts—edification through love.

Paul’s Consistency: Paul's statement in 1 Corinthians 13:2 ("If I have all faith so as to move mountains but do not have love, I am nothing") does not diminish the importance of faith but highlights that faith devoid of love is incomplete. This aligns with Jesus's teaching in Matthew 22:37–40, where love is presented as the greatest commandment.


Love as the Greatest Gift
The elevation of love above faith and hope in 1 Corinthians 13:13 is consistent with the eschatological context. While faith and hope pertain to the present life (trust in God and anticipation of the future), love endures eternally, reflecting the very nature of God (cf. 1 John 4:8).
Textual Argument
The manuscript evidence does not suggest that 1 Corinthians 13 is a later addition. It is present in all early copies of the text, with no significant textual variants indicating its absence or alteration. This continuity reinforces its authenticity.
Conclusion
The linguistic and theological arguments strongly suggest that 1 Corinthians 13 is an integral part of Paul's original letter. The use of εἰδῶ throughout chapters 12–14 reflects a cohesive style, and the theological content aligns with Paul's broader teaching. The chapter's placement is deliberate, serving to ground the discussion of spiritual gifts in the central Christian ethic of love. Thus, the arguments for its insertion by another writer or even by Paul as an afterthought are unconvincing.
